# Jenkins retrieve active choice parameter in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters

I have one Active Choice Parameter called ENVIRONMENT.  I want to use that parameter in my next Active Choice Parameter.  How do I retrieve the previous choice?

Here is my code.  I cannot figure out how to retrieve the ENVIRONMENT variable from the previous parameter and assign it to my env variable in my new groovy script for my second variable.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

String env = $ENVIRONMENT

def output = []
def db = [url:'jdbc:oracle:thin:@database_host:1521:SID', user:'username', password:'password', driver:'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
String sqlString = ("select distinct logical_host from SERVER_NAME_VW where app='ME' and env = ${env} order by 1")

sql.eachRow(sqlString){ row ->  
    output.push(row[0])
}

return output
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the incorrect parameter type for the job.

You need to change the parameter type to

> Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter

Which allows you to add the ENVIRONMENT parameter as a referenced parameter.

For more information, see the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) documentation

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed to use.